# How to test extension implementations

Tags: junit5

There are several extension points available in the JUnit 5 API.

For example:

- [`AfterEachCallback`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterEachCallback.html)
- [`AfterAllCallback`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterAllCallback.html)
- [`AfterTestExecutionCallback`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/AfterTestExecutionCallback.html)
- [`BeforeAllCallback`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeAllCallback.html)
- [`BeforeEachCallback`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeEachCallback.html)
- [`BeforeTestExecutionCallback`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeTestExecutionCallback.html)
- [`ExecutionCondition`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExecutionCondition.html)
- [`ParameterResolver`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ParameterResolver.html)
- [`TestExecutionExceptionHandler`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestExecutionExceptionHandler.html)
- [`TestInstancePostProcessor`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstancePostProcessor.html)
- [`TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestTemplateInvocationContextProvider.html)

Nearly all of these extensions take some form of [`ExtensionContext`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html) which provides access to the [test class](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html#getRequiredTestClass--), [test method](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html#getRequiredTestMethod--), [test instance](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html#getRequiredTestInstance--), ability to [publish report entries](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html#publishReportEntry-java.util.Map-), [store values](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.html#getStore-org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace-), and other capabilities. A lot of these operate directly on class instances

Most implementations will probably use some combination of [reflection using `ReflectionSupport`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/commons/support/ReflectionSupport.html) and [annotation discovery using `AnnotationSupport`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/commons/support/AnnotationSupport.html), which are all static methods, which makes them difficult to mock.

Now, say I have written an implementation of the `ExecutionCondition`, or an extension that implements both the `BeforeEachCallback` and `AfterEachCallback` - how do I effectively test them?

I guess I could mock `ExtensionContext`, but that doesn't seem like a good way to effectively exercise the different code paths.

Internally to JUnit, there is the [`ExecutionEventRecorder`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-platform-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/platform/engine/test/event/ExecutionEventRecorder.java) and it is used along with the [`JupiterTestEngine` implementation for execution (which is `@API(status=INTERNAL)`)](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/41c76d6a703e0b8b287fb5bbc36b98660ed29875/junit-jupiter-params/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTestIntegrationTests.java#L178-L180) to select and execute the tests, and then [perform assertions on the resulting events](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/41c76d6a703e0b8b287fb5bbc36b98660ed29875/junit-jupiter-params/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTestIntegrationTests.java#L173-L175).

I could make use of the same pattern because of the `public` visibility on the `JupiterTestEngine`.

---

Here are a few concrete examples to demonstrate:

1. An `ExecutionCondition` that enables tests based on system properties. This can possibly be tested with some reflection and using [`TestInfo`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInfo.html) in a `@BeforeEach` or `@AfterEach` style, but it seems more complicated to deal with and possible issues when parallel test execution comes. This example shows an example of "how do I provide a real-life `ExtensionContext` and assert on the result".

   ```java
   @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @ExtendWith(SystemPropertyCondition.class)
   public @interface SystemProperty {
     String key();
     String value();
   }

   public class SystemPropertyCondition implements ExecutionCondition {
     @Override
     public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(final ExtensionContext context) {
       return context.getTestMethod()
           .flatMap(element -> AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(element, SystemProperty.class))
           .map(systemProperty -> {
             if (systemProperty.value().equals(System.getProperty(systemProperty.key()))) {
               return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("Property is available");
             } else {
               return ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("Property not equal");
             }
           })
           .orElseGet(() -> ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("No annotations"));
     }
   }
   ```
2. An `ExecutionCondition` that only runs on the provided day of the week. How would a test clock be injected? How would you test if the condition was the expected result? I guess some state/implementations can be placed into a [`ExtensionContext.Store`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExtensionContext.Store.html) which would allow for some sort of state being passed between extensions (like with a `BeforeEachCallback` as well, which might be the right path, but that is going to depend on the ordering of extension execution. I don't believe `BeforeEachCallback` is called before an `ExecutionCondition`, so that path might not be the right one. This example shows both the "how do I inject dependencies" and also shows the same issue as the previous example of providing the `ExtensionContext` and asserting on the result.

   ```java
   @ExtendWith(RunOnDayCondition.class)
   public @interface RunOnDay {
     DayOfWeek[] value();
   }

   final class RunOnDayCondition implements ExecutionCondition {

     private static final ConditionEvaluationResult DEFAULT = disabled(
         RunOnDay.class + " is not present"
     );

     @Override
     public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(final ExtensionContext context) {
       return context.getElement()
           .flatMap(annotatedElement -> findAnnotation(annotatedElement, RunOnDay.class))
           .map(RunOnDay::value)
           .map(RunOnDayCondition::evaluateIfRunningOnDay)
           .orElse(DEFAULT);
     }

     private static ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateIfRunningOnDay(final DayOfWeek[] days) {
       // TODO: How would you inject a test clock?
       final DayOfWeek currentDay = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek();
       final boolean runningInday = Stream.of(days).anyMatch(currentDay::equals);

       if (runningInday) {
         return enabled("Current day is " + currentDay + ", in the specified days of " + Arrays.toString(days));
       } else {
         return disabled("Current day is " + currentDay + ", not in the specified days of " + Arrays.toString(days));
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. An extension that sets up a temporary directory, provides it as a parameter, and then cleans it up after the test. This would use `ParameterResolver`, `BeforeEachCallback`, `AfterEachCallback`, and the `ExtensionContext.Store`. This example shows that an extension implementation may use multiple extensions points and can make use of the store to keep track of state.

Would a custom test engine for extension tests be the right approach?

So, how do I test various extension implementations without relying on internal APIs and without "duplicating" effort into mocks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check that JUnit Extension throws specific Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237611/check-that-junit-extension-throws-specific-exception)

Answer (score 1):

I know that is not a complete answer (but I am on mobile now and your question is very complex)... Try however if 
[this project](https://github.com/JeffreyFalgout/junit5-extensions/tree/master/extension-testing) could help you.

If you limit a little your question I could try to help you better

Answer (score 0):

Since *JUnit 5.4*, you can use [*Test Kit*](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#testkit) to test your extensions. The feature seems to become stable with *JUnit 5.7*. (Note that the API has changed between these versions.)

With Test Kit, you can execute mock-tests within actual tests and perform assertions on the result. Note that you probably need to prevent your *mock tests* from beeing discovered directly. [Issue #1779 of JUnit 5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1779) might help you with that.